# select one row's id in case of multiple max values in sql

Tags: mysql

I want to select only the id which has the maximum precedence with the following table (table1) whose item_id is 1001.

table1

```
id  | plan_id | item_id | plan_item_bundle_id | precedence 
-----+---------+---------+---------------------+------------

 401 |         |    1001 |                     |         -1

 402 |         |    1001 |                     |         -1
```

How can I do it ? Thanks

I dont care if the precedence is same, any one would do. 
Thanks

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. *which has the maximum preference*: which preference? *whose user_id is 91*: what is user_id? I'm sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
select id from table1 where precedence =(select max(precedence) from table1)
```

Comment: Dont forget the other condition, and I also tried
select id from table1 where precedence = (select max(precedence) from table1) and item_id=1001;

Gave me
401
402
as output

Comment: do you want only one id? then add limit 1 at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from table1
group by id, prededence
having precedence = max(precedence )
Limit 0, 1
```

Comment: ERROR:  column "table1.precedence" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: i didnt tested it, you can change the group by to `group by id, prededence`

Comment: select id from table1 where item_id=1001 group by id,precedence having precedence = max(precedence);
Still gives me
401   
402

Comment: perecedence has value as `-1` for both 401 and 402, so what exactly do you need?

Comment: OP says *if the precedence is same, any one would do*, so take one :)

Comment: at the end of the query use `limit 0, 1`

Comment: I've already gave him this answer but OP says it's wrong (watch comments under my answer). It sounds really strange, anyway I told him to just use `LIMIT 1`...

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 
WHERE precedence = MAX(precedence)
  AND item_id = 1001
LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM table1 
WHERE precedence = (SELECT MAX(precedence) FROM table1)
  AND item_id = 1001
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: ERROR:  LIMIT #,# syntax is not supported
LINE 1: ...ere precedence = MAX(precedence) and item_id=1001 limit 0,1 ...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Use separate LIMIT and OFFSET clauses.

Comment: Thanks !! Works now but I dont want to use limit because this is a part of an inner query which is now something like
having precedence = max(precedence) limit 1
 inner join plan_item_price_timeline pipt on pipt.plan_item_id = pli.id
  which now throws the error 

ERROR: syntax error at or near "inner"

Comment: @NikhilSharma: I'm so sorry, but you **should** learn how to ask a question!! You wrote a lot of nonsense you had to edit before we could even understand what you were asking us; finally, when many answers were provided, you told us you cannot use `LIMIT`...

Comment: :My appologies, but I have already marked your answer as correct just because it solves my original question. 
  
And I had not known that LIMIT would not work. If I would have known I would have specified at the start.  Thanks for answering

Comment: I'm so sorry, but you should learn to be patient and let the question settle by giving it the asker 5 min to review it.
And btw, you also did not provide the correct answer in the first go. So, lesson to be learnt is to err is human. 
Thanks